# image folder - heroku precompile

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, precompile, heroku-toolbelt

When I run the following command:

```
heroku run rake assets:precompile
```

My css, javascripts and anything in the root of my public folder is precompiled...however, my image folder (which is in the public folder) is not precompiled.

How can I ensure that my public folder is precompiled (I want them to be on my cdn, per the steps here...https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/cdn-asset-host-rails31)?

Answer (score 0):

Assets in `public` are not precompiled. If your assets need precompiling, put them in `app/assets` (and or adjust your config settings to look in other places).

From [Ruby on Rails Asset Pipeline Guide:](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#preprocessing%23how-to-use-the-asset-pipeline):

> Assets can still be placed in the public hierarchy. Any assets under
>   public will be served as static files by the application or web
>   server. You should use app/assets for files that must undergo some
>   pre-processing before they are served.